# what is equivalent UpdateSourceTrigger in C# winform?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, data-binding, binding

I have question. what is equivalent UpdateSourceTrigger in C# windows application?

```
public static void Bind(ComboBox cmb, ComboVAlidationRule vld)
        {
            Binding bndControl = new Binding("DataBind");
            bndControl.Source = vld;
            bndControl.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            bndControl.ValidationRules.Add(vld);
            cmb.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, bndControl);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Binding.DataSourceUpdateMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.datasourceupdatemode.aspx) is what you're looking for.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

// ...

    Binding binding = new Binding("Text", this.personBindingSource, "Name");
    binding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;

    this.nameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` isn't used in Winforms, right?

Comment: @LuckyLikey It *is* used in WinForms and works properly when objects implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz45s2bh.aspx)